# Group Concat for merge 2 row sql table and separate column value

Tags: php, codeigniter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUxL1.jpg)Im trying to merge 2 row on sql table to 1 row, and get 1 value of row 2 for fill column in row 1 like shown in image, what metode should i use to get table like that? Thanks,

actually this table use join 2 tables on sql, and i should do like shown in image,

Like shown in image,

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the result shown in the image and merge two rows into one row while concatenating column values, you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function along with GROUP BY in SQL. Assuming you have a table with two rows like this:

Original Table:

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Val1 |
| 1 | John | Val2 |

You can use the following SQL query to merge the rows based on the ID and Name columns while concatenating the "Value" column:

```sql
SELECT
  ID,
  Name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Value SEPARATOR ', ') AS Merged_Values
FROM
  your_table_name
GROUP BY
  ID, Name;
```

The result will be:

Merged Table:

| ID | Name | Merged_Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Val1, Val2 |

Explanation:

1. The GROUP_CONCAT function is used to concatenate the "Value" column values with a separator (in this case, a comma and a space ', ').
2. The GROUP BY clause groups the rows with the same ID and Name together, and the aggregate function (GROUP_CONCAT) works on each group individually.

Keep in mind that the syntax may vary slightly depending on the database system you are using (e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server). Make sure to replace "your_table_name" with the actual name of your table in the SQL query.

Also, please note that the GROUP_CONCAT function may have a limit on the maximum length of the concatenated string, depending on the database settings. If you have a large number of values to concatenate, you might need to handle this limitation accordingly.

Comment: how if  the table result i want is Value1 | Value2 in 1 row?